problem with installing strapi in an astro project
after I run the command
npx create-strapi-app@latest my-project --quickstart

as shown in the strapi website I get this error and I don't know why:
Error while installing dependencies:
npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
npm WARN config optional Use `--omit=optional` to exclude optional dependencies, or
npm WARN config `--include=optional` to include them.

.....

npm ERR! Error: Expected "0.19.11" but got "0.21.4"
npm ERR!     at validateBinaryVersion (C:\Users\moham\Desktop\technical-test\cms-try\my-project\node_modules\esbuild\install.js:133:11)
npm ERR!     at C:\Users\moham\Desktop\technical-test\cms-try\my-project\node_modules\esbuild\install.js:284:5
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Node.js v20.9.0

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-06-02T21_54_21_159Z-debug-0.log
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addBreadcrumb')
    at C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\2d56dd13733e9da7\node_modules\@strapi\generate-new\dist\utils\usage.js:36:31
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Module.captureStderr (C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\2d56dd13733e9da7\node_modules\@strapi\generate-new\dist\utils\usage.js:35:37)
    at createProject (C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\2d56dd13733e9da7\node_modules\@strapi\generate-new\dist\create-project.js:133:17)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async createQuickStartProject (C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\2d56dd13733e9da7\node_modules\@strapi\generate-new\dist\create-quickstart-project.js:18:3)

I thought that the node version isn't compatible with strapi but I'm using v20.9.0 which is declared to be compatible in their website
I genuinely have no idea what's going on
I thought it was the node version but I'm using v20.9.0 which seems to be supported by strapi

Are you executing this in the folder of an existing astro project? I think it's meant to be run in its own project / folder / git repo.

I tried both, I executed it in an astro project then in a folder of its own but I got the same result

The error does not refer to the node version, but to the esbuild version. The error comes from this line in esbuild, that seems to compare your installed esbuild version to the version field in its package.json.
So probably your local packages are messed up. Try removing the folders C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\npm-cache and make sure to execute the command in an empty folder, not inside an existing project (astro or otherwise).
